# Unable to initialise App Check for Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am trying to run a callable cloud function on the emulator but I'm failing because the app check is not successful

Here's the launcher activity of my app. The activity calling the function is different.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

---

The error I'm getting is:

```
W/FirebaseContextProvider: Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead.
Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed: 1:<number>:android<number>:
```

I don't get how I should be initialising App Check instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SafetyNet Attestation fails in flutter because access to your Firebase resources without a valid device is not possible.

There is this wonderful guide to set this up in FlutterFire do check
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage/

Comment: This works...i also found it in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android-debug-provider)

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a real device and have followed the official guideline. Do you have any ideas on what can I do to fix it?

Comment: That guide worked for me, flutter clean ?

Comment: Link broken, please update or describe what the guide says in the answer. Also SafetyNet is deprecated and cannot be used on new projects. Play Integrity is required